# is Krishna bhagwan also known as Mara

Tags: scripture, krishna, gods, asuras, buddha

Is Krishna Bhagawan - the sage-hero-god from Mahabharata- also known as Mara?  I don't know much, so this is just some speculation. Mara is the villian in Buddha's story.

there is this post:
https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/47558/is-krishna-a-demon

Comment: From Hindu side, I don't think there is any name of Lord Krishna as Mara but there is not so well known Goddess Mara or Mrityu who is Goddess of death.

Comment: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.3.02.irel.html

Comment: That is a Buddhist text. I wrote from Hinduism's side but still I think there is some confusion as Krishna word is freely used in old texts for 'dark'. For example, In some Veda Krishna-Ayas(dark metal) is used for Iron. Krishna paksh refers to full moon. Both these words don't have anything to do with Hindu God Krishna. It is possible that Mara may have been called dark because he is villain and your translator went one step and called it Krishna. He any way isn't aware enough to comment on Hinduism because in foot notes, he places Krishna as Hindu cupid which is totally wrong.

Comment: Hindu cupid will be Kamadev. God of desire and sex with bow and arrow.

Comment: so kamadev is mara? you should write comment as answer, not comment..

Comment: No you didn't get what I was saying. First part: I am just saying Mara is being referred as Kanha/Krishna which means dark because he is the bad guy. Krishna doesn't need to be always referring to God Krishn because it is a word in itself and has been used many times without referring to God so here it may have been just being used to refer to Mara as dark. Mara doesn't need to be any Hindu figure.

Comment: @Rambhakt okie-dokie..

Comment: Second: I pointed out folly of translator in the link you mentioned. If he doesn't know that Hindu cupid is Kama not Krishna then how can he make a big claim of Mara being Krishna

Comment: regardless, you should post the answer and i will accept it

Comment: What do you want me to write in the answer? Answer will be of only one line i.e. my first comment. I have to write rest of it in response to link you shared in the comment section

Answer (score 1):

Before starting my answer i want to clear 1 thing. The Krishna, i am going to mention here is from rig veda with Sri Sayanacharya's commentary. Neither me nor Sayana confirm him to be as Devaki Putra. So, just see him as an individual.

From Vedas,

Now, Rig Veda tells us about a story of Asura Krishna who lived near Yamuna and was creating havoc all around. So, request by Guru Brihaspati Lord Indra along the Marut ganas slayed this Krishna.

Now, The word "asa" means breath and the word Asura would mean who has his strength in the breath or who is the possessed of breath,
**this is the meaning given by yaksha nirukta.** That means an asura is someone who is posser of breath that he could perform Great actions by his power or a very powerful supreme Being.

> *ता हि **देवानामसुरा** तावर्या ता नः क्षितीः करतमूर्जयन्तीः । अश्याम मित्रावरुणा वयं वां द्यावा च यत्र पीपयन्नहा च ॥*
>
> *For they are **Mighty (Asuras) of Gods,** the friendly make, both of you, our lands exceeding fruitful.(Rig Veda 7.65.2).*

Here, Varuna-Mirta as called asuras as they are very powerful beings and similiarly, many powerful deities like Rudra, Indra, Agni, Vishnu, Soma have been called asuras in various hyms of vedas.

Sayana also translated Asura as mighty and gave its meaning as follows.:

> *asurā < asura
> [noun], nominative, dual, masculine
> **“Asura; lord; asura [word];** sulfur.”*

So, moving ahead.:

1. In this, Verse of [8.96.11](https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-5b498408a4ec60bb404ef40ac6d8e001-lq), Sayana in his commentry says, Krishna = Soma. Plus, he also says that Amsumati = Yamuna = Sunlight. Yamuna is the daughter of Sun. So, Krishna covered thea Sun.
2. In the Verse [8.96.13](https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-1c84013f81d3f7be3b9d488d7862a574-lq), is the verse which says about Indra slaying Krishna.
3. Verse [8.96.16](https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-27f7fa330b00b7eda566b6e59554a018-lq), Sayana says that Indra is the enemy of Krishna, Vrittra, **Namuchi**, etc (Viz the darkness).
4. Verse [1.130.8](https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-f3ba9ec4e71b3bdb05b4206c88edafcd-lq), Here, Arya means light and Krishna means dark. No Aryan-Dravid Theory as per as I understand it's just good and bad.
5. Verse [1.101.1](https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-9160130cd1546df1e26620a09b4a23a4-lq), So, here he says, Krishna = Vritra = black cloud. Rigveda also says Vritra was born from manas (moon) as vritra is our inner demon and avidya. And negative thoughts always comes from mind (manas) only. Which can be diminished by buddhi/intellect (Sun) through knowledge (Vajra).

Thus, When Black Cloud (Krishna/Vritra/Avidya) covers the Sun (Intellect). Then, by the direction of a Guru (Brihaspati), Indra (Knowledge/lightning) and Maruts (wind/pranas) through pranayama wind takes the clouds away and lightning vanishes it. Thus, revealing the Sun (intellect) once again.

**Conclusion.:** Krishna of Rig Veda leads many dark asuras to Yamuna. He is identified with **Namuchi**, Vrittra, etc. I think the description matches with the Buddhist one to some extent.

I am giving pics instead of verses with commentaries, as it will keep the answer short.

Another thing, just some synonyms.:

- Mara in Sanskrit means Death.
- Krishna in Sanskrit means Black.
- But, Kala in Sanskrit means Time, Death and Black.

Anyways, that's it. Whatever i know i have written that's my own opinion.

|| Om Tat Sat ||

Comment: Ok, if yo think so. Anyways, babye, cya . Tc.

Comment: It's ok, I don't give a damn about the chrckmark or whatever, n don't want it. Just do 1 thing, later on, when ur lord calls u to tell about his feelings, keep it to urself. I don't want n need to hear about it. Period. Got it. Just don't message me that's what my 1st message was all about right, k **don't message and disturb me. Goodbye.**